# Problem in restoring database from PostgreSQL Version 11

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, restore, pgadmin

I am trying to restore database from PostgreSQL Version 11 into PostgreSQL Version 10.
I am using Windows 7 (32-bit) so I can't use the latest [PostgreSQL Version](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/). So I am using PostgreSQL Version 10.

But I am taking backup from database of PostgreSQL Version 11.
Because of which I am getting error:

`pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header`

***So, is there any way I can restore my database in PostgreSQL Version 10.***

It would be really helpful if any can show me a way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pg_restore from the newer version to create a plain SQL dump file.  Then restore to the older version from that dump file.  Depending on what features you are using, the dump file may need to be manually edited before it will restore successfully.

Comment: I have created some procedures in that database which I want to restore in my Postgresql 10. But procedures are not supported by Postgresql 10. So, how am I suppose to do that?

Comment: @Jay You can't.  If you want to use modern features, you need to use modern versions, and at some point you also need modern hardware.